# Getting original string with lxml tostring()

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I'm using lxml and I'm trying to get the original xml string so:

```
>>> elem = etree.fromstring("<tag>áéíóúñü</tag>")
>>> etree.tostring(elem)
b'<tag>&#225;&#233;&#237;&#243;&#250;&#241;&#252;</tag>'
```

The only way that I found to get the original string is doing:

```
>>> etree.tostring(elem, encoding = "utf-8").decode("utf-8")
'<tag>áéíóúñü</tag>'
```

Is there a better aproach?

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
In [31]: elem = etree.fromstring("<tag>❄</tag>")

In [32]: etree.tostring(elem, encoding=str)
Out[32]: '<tag>❄</tag>'
```